# Execute command from specific folder

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

I have a screenshot tool that only works if I start it from the same directory where the file is in. 
Now I want to make a shortcut to just press print, the command is:

```
bash -c '~/Documents/KneckPrint | xsel --clipboard'
```

Now as I said, this doesn't work if I don't execute it from the KneckPrint folder.

I've tried

```
bash -c 'cd ~/Documents/KneckPrint | KneckPrint | xsel --clipboard'
```

But that doesn't work so I'm left clueless.

E: the `bash -c '…'` seems to be necessary because otherwise xsel doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 2):

Julie Pelletier suggested (in comments):

```
bash -c 'cd ~/Documents/KneckPrint && KneckPrint | xsel --clipboard'
```

A shorter variant of this would be

```
( cd ~/Documents/KneckPrint && KneckPrint | xsel --clipboard )
```

This (or Julie's suggestion) could be put into a shell function:

```
function knecksel {
  ( cd "$HOME/Documents/KneckPrint" && KneckPrint | xsel --clipboard )
}
```

The subshell (`(...)`) prevents the directory from remaining changed when the `xsel` command finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create rc-file on the fly:
`bash --rcfile <(cd directory) -c 'command line'`